# wxTheApp problems: Undeclared identifier using msvc10

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, object-files, undeclared-identifier

Which header file to include for this pointer ? I want to make a simple dialogue box with two buttons "Hello world" and "Close". But for OnClose function I typed wxTheApp->Exit() inside it, and my msvc10 compiler says ,"undeclared identifier: wxTheApp". I included wx\app.h in the program also, but now although it is compiling that part fine, it is showing 100's of errors in the obj files of the files i included in the project. One such error is
`HelloframeGUI.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual enum wxLayoutDirection __cdecl wxWindow::GetLayoutDirection(void)const " (?GetLayoutDirection@wxWindow@@UEBA?AW4wxLayoutDirection@@XZ)`

Can anyone help please ?

```
#include "HelloframeGUI.h"
#include "wx/msgdlg.h"
#include "wx/app.h"

HelloframeGUI::HelloframeGUI( wxWindow* parent )
:
Helloframe( parent )
{

}

void HelloframeGUI::OnShowMessage( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    wxMessageBox( wxT("wxFormBuilder Tutorial") );// TODO: Implement OnShowMessage
}

void HelloframeGUI::OnClose( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    wxTheApp->Exit();// TODO: Implement OnClose
}
```

Comment: You said that after including `wx\app.h` you no longer have the "undeclared identifier" error, so why use that as your title? These errors are linker errors. Most likely you 1) didn't compile the wxWidgets libraries, or 2) add these lib-file names and directories to your project settings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like wxTheApp problem is solved. Anyway, I usually use  wxGetApp() for this:  wxGetApp().Close().  wxGetApp requires including of application h-file (should be part of your project). Regadring linker errors, this is the list of minimal required wxWidgets libraries:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#pragma comment (lib, "wxmsw28ud_core.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "wxbase28ud.lib")
#else
#pragma comment (lib, "wxmsw28u_core.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "wxbase28u.lib")
#endif

#pragma comment (lib, "comctl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "rpcrt4.lib")
```

Add it to one of .cpp files. If your project is not Unicode, remove "u" from the library names.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to close the top level window - in your case wxDialog in order for application to be finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a bit too late, don't you think? 

Lol.